# Get data from a raster using two coordinate arrays with Python

Tags: python, gdal, numpy, array

I'm trying to find a function in Python, that given two arrays with geographic coordinates, returns a list or array of raster values in those positions. that is to say:

```
import numpy as np
"""geog coordinates on x axis """
xc = [878571.041, 878583.54109659, 878596.04119319]
""" geographical coordinates on y axis """
yc = [187189.14, 187176.64015077, 187164.14030153]
"""list to array"""
x = np.array (xc)
y = np.array (yc)
"""raster values at those coordinates"""
z = function (x y) 
or
z = function (xc, yc)
```

The output I expect is an array with raster values in the x, y positions. Is there a function in GDAL, Python or any other library that allows me to do this? Or must I necessarily use a `for` loop to obtain these values.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able do this in [rasterio](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio._io.html#rasterio._io.DatasetReaderBase.sample) with `sample`:

```
with rasterio.open("example.tif") as src:
    values = np.array(src.sample(zip(Xc, Yc)))
```