# Altitude extraction from a DEM(.tiff) file using Python

Tags: python, dem, geotiff-tiff

I have a DEM(.tiff) file and I need to know the altitude of certain points(coordinates).

I opened it like this:

```
import tifffile as tiff
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import rasterio

tfile = tiff.imread('ms.tif')
tfile.shape
tiff.imshow(tfile)
```

Then I've got this image:

[image]

I just need some function to get altitude to my points, not the full code.

Comment: After reading my answer and note that maybe you don't have the rows and columns. In that case are your coordinates in the same CRS that your DEM

Comment: See also https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/307427/2856

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a easy task with `rasterio`. For each band [the data is accessible](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#reading-raster-data) as a kind of array.

So:

```py
import rasterio

# Which band are you interested. 
# 1 if there is only one band
band_of_interest = 1

# Row and Columns of the raster you want to know
# the value
row_of_interest = 30
column_of_interest = 50

# open the raster and close it automatically
# See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369526
with rasterio.open('example.tif') as dataset:
    band = dataset.read(band_of_interest)
    value_of_interest = band(row_of_interest, column_of_interest)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create a points dataset from the coordinates then use the [Extract Values To Points tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/geostatistical-analyst/extract-values-to-table.htm), if using ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro.